# Converting data into binary within a data frame

Tags: r, binary

This table is called 'temp'

```
   No. of times   Clear   Included    Percentage
         2           1        1           0.50
         4           0        1           0.60
         0           0        0           0.20
```

For example, if I have this data set, I want to be converting all numbers above 0 under the 'No. of times' column to a 1 and leaving the 0 as it is.

Overall I'm wanting a data set looking like this

```
    No. of times   Clear   Included    Percentage
         1           1        1           0.50
         1           0        1           0.60
         0           0        0           0.20
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, you are using the terms `data.frame`, `data.table` and `table` interchangeably, which is a mistake.  They are distinct classes of R objects and you should not use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 5):

```
temp[ ,"No. of times"] <- sign(temp[ ,"No. of times"])
```

Comment: I tried your way but the output was a list of all the numbers. I want the numbers to be incorporated back within the data table format I've shown above. How is this done?

Comment: Sounds like you only ran the right part. sign(temp[ ,"No. of times"])

If you type print(temp) you will see the whole thing :)

Answer (score 3):

great place to use [`ifelse`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html)

```
 temp$`No. of times` <- ifelse(temp$`No. of times` > 0, 1, 0)
```

---

As an aside, you might want to use

```
names(temp) <- make.names(names(temp))
```

Comment: I tried your first method with ifelse, but the output was a list of all the numbers. I want the numbers to be incorporated within the data table format I've shown above. How is this done?

Comment: Did you run what I have above?  It is getting assigned back into `temp`, so use `print(temp)`.  Also, is your object a `data.table` or a `data.frame`  (are you calling `library(data.table)` in your code?)

Comment: No prob, glad it helped.  Personally, I like @WilmerEHenaoH 's method better.  You might want to give it a check mark ;)

Answer (score 2):

A trick, but

```
temp[ , "No. of times"] <- (temp[ , "No. of times"] > 0) + 0
```

will also do the operation you want. I say a trick, because the part in parentheses `(temp[ , "No. of times"] > 0)` evaluates to a logical which is then coerced to `0` or `1` through the addition with `0`.